# Python game and trying to utilize pygame.mixer.Sound.play() to add sound effects

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

First, I am brand new to this site, so if I am doing something wrong or incorrect, please feel free to say so. I am writing a game in PyCharm for a class. The game is finished and it works. I wanted to also add different sound effects for each room when the player enters the room (12 rooms). I can utilize pygame and it works. My issue is I am using multi-dimensional dictionaries and cannot figure out how to utilize pygame to play the sound clip from the dictionary (or if it is even possible). I am only going to place part of the code below. If more is needed, please feel free to let me know.

The code (partial):

```
"""  Scenario: Recall that the game requires players to type in a command line prompt to move through the different rooms and get items from each room. The game's goal is for the player to get all the items before encountering the room containing the villain. Each step of the game will require a text output to let the player know where they are in the game and an option of whether to obtain the item in each room. """

# -----------------------------

import time
import textwrap
from playsound import playsound
import pygame
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init()


# load sound clips
creepy = pygame.mixer.Sound("creepy.wav")    # creepy music box
bees = pygame.mixer.Sound("bees.wav")    # bees flying
door = pygame.mixer.Sound("door.wav")    # door opening





  #    <skipped code>


def main():
    # format for the rooms ->  {effect (either a sound or a poem), description, available directional movements,
    # and item (if available).}

    rooms = {
    # starting point of the game
    'The U.S.S. Sulaco Central Console Realm': {
        'effect': 'You are hearing sounds of evil man laughing coming from all directions.',
        'effect2': 'seveneight.wav',
        'descr': 'You have just entered the \033[36mThe U.S.S. Sulaco Central Console Realm\033[00m. The Queen '
                 'has been laying her eggs early, hoping her facehugger alien children will hatch in time. So, '
                 'escape down one of the corridors! You can move \033[93mNorth\033[00m, \033[93mSouth\033[00m, '
                 '\033[93mEast\033[00m, or \033[93mWest\033[00m.',
        'North': 'Underground Florida Military Bunker Realm',
        'South': 'New York Realm',
        'East': 'Cabrini Green Warehouse Realm',
        'West': 'Blackhole 3'},

    'Underground Florida Military Bunker Realm': {
        'effect': 'Seven, eight, gonna stay up late...',
        'effect2': 'seveneight.wav',
        'descr': 'You have just entered the \033[36mUnderground Florida Military Bunker Realm\033[00m. The horde '
                 'of zombies has suddenly disappeared from the grounds around the underground bunker. However, '
                 'the scientists and soldiers are still reluctant to leave. Still, they are closing in on a cure '
                 'with these newly developed vaccines. You can move \033[93mSouth\033[00m, \033[93mEast\033[00m, '
                 'or \033[93mWest\033[00m.',
        'South': 'The U.S.S. Sulaco Central Console Realm',
        'East': 'Blackhole 1',
        'West': 'Morningside Cemetery Mausoleum Realm',
        'item': 'Hypnocil Shots'},
}




    #    <skipped code>




    # Check if the player enters a command to move to a new room
    if len(move) >= 2 and move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
        current_room = move_between_rooms(current_room, move[1], rooms)
        open_realm_door()
        time.sleep(4)
        print('\n{}'.format(rooms[current_room]['effect']))
        time.sleep(4)
        # open_realm_door()
        star_divider(25)
        print(textwrap.fill((rooms[current_room]['descr']), 100))
        **effect3 = (rooms[current_room]['effect2'])
        print(effect3)    # make sure the right sound clip is being passed
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play("effect3")**
        time.sleep(6)

        continue

   


    #    <skipped code>
```

The error that I get is:

*File "D:\Documents\sounds\73ProjectTwoTextBasedGame.py", line 423, in main
pygame.mixer.Sound.play("effect3")
TypeError: descriptor 'play' for 'Sound' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object*

Comment: Are you expecting your sounds to be in a dictionary?  If so, can you please include the code that creates the dictionary.

Comment: Hi Kingsley. I have added two entries into the dictionary called "rooms," and the sound effect names are located in the key called "effects2". For example, when the current room is the 'Underground Florida Military Bunker Realm' then the effects2 sound effect name  'seveneight.wav' should be placed into the pygame command pygame.mixer.Sound.play("effect2") so the particular sound will play when a player enters this room. I hope this adds some clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what your intention is.   But based on the error message, and the existing code, the problem reads like you expect to have a dictionary of sounds.

*One* way of doing this is to load your dictionary with the sounds effect names as keys:

```
sound_effects = {}
for effect_name in [ "creepy.wav", "bees.wav", "door.wav" ]:  # and the rest
    basename = effect_name.split( '.' )[0]
    sound_effects[basename] = pygame.mixer.Sound( effect_name )
```

Then later in the code, your playback should work:

```
pygame.mixer.Sound.play( sound_effects["creepy"] )
```

That way your game locations only need to store the name of the sound they wish to play.

Maybe it would be good to wrap all the sound playback into a function, so it's more convenient to handle & report errors:

```
def playSoundEffect( name ):
    global sound_effects

    if ( name not in sound_effects ):
        sys.stderr.write( "Request to play unknown sound effect [" + name + "]\n" )
    else:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play( sound_effects[name] )
```

Working this into your existing code (note: *really* guessing here) ~

```
    effect3 = (rooms[current_room]['effect2'])
    print(effect3)    # make sure the right sound clip is being passed
    
    playSoundEffect( effect3 )
    time.sleep(6)
```

BTW: you only need to call `pygame.init()` once, outside any loops.